# Deserialize Date in Marshmallow

Tags: python, date-formatting, marshmallow

I have a Table (START_DATE , TEXT ,DECIMAL , INTEGER).
I read the data from the DB and try to de serialize the data.

```
class Response(Schema):
    class Meta:
        json_module = simplejson
    data = fields.List(fields.List(fields.Raw()))
```

Response:

```
"data": [
        [
            "Tue, 26 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
            "USD",
            78790.400000,
            79262
        ],
        [
            "Mon, 25 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
            "USD",
            68852.340000,
            77365
        ]
```

How can I change the dateformat to '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
I did the below change but no change in the date format.

```
class Response(Schema):
    class Meta:
        json_module = simplejson
        dateformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
    data = fields.List(fields.List(fields.Raw()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The date format won't apply magically to any string looking like a data.

You need to specify fields for each value.

From you sample, your schema could look like

```
class Response(Schema):
    data = fields.Tuple((
        fields.DateTime(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'),
        fields.String(),
        fields.Float(),
        fields.Integer(),
    ))
```

Comment: The data in the question is coming from a database. For Simplicity purpose I have changed the column limit to 4. The data that comes from the DB has 100+ columns.
All the columns are automatically identified by field.raw.
My question is when marshmallow identifies the type to be dateformat instead of regular dateformat can we change it to something custom.

The suggestion that you provide is correct when we pre-know the type of column and their type. But in my case the column list is huge and we query from many differnt tables.

Comment: OK, I totally forgot about the inferred field feature. But it only applies to fields declared in Meta, like fields = ('birthdate', 'name').

Comment: Here you're using the Raw field and the data is passed as is without marshmallow knowing anything about its type. I think it displays as a datetime string because that's what str(data) would look like, not because marshmallow serializes it as a datetime.

Comment: Thanks Jerome. It looks like the there is nothing we can do on the marshmallow side. The database is formatting the datetime and sending that as a String.

Comment: I'm afraid so. I'm surprised the driver doesn't return a datetime object. But even if it did, marshmallow's Raw field wouldn't treat it as a datetime.

Comment: Yes exactly and that's why marshmallow was not making any modification to the output. it acts a pipe to what comes from DB when using the fields.raw feature.

`[(datetime.date(2021, 1, 27), 'USD', Decimal('71639.470000'), 80629), (datetime.date(2021, 1, 26), 'USD', Decimal('78790.400000'), 79262), (datetime.date(2021, 1, 25), 'USD', Decimal('68852.340000'), 77365)` 

This is what the DB was returning, the change was being done by Flask jsonify which can be handled easily by creating a customJSONEncoder.

Comment: Yes that may be suited to your use case. Using marshmallow would require building schemas dynamically which might be too muyh trouble and in fact quite bad performance-wise anyway.